# Ошибка NoReverseMatch Python Django

Tags: django

Ошибка возникает при переходе по ссылке:

```
<a href="{% url 'catalog:catalog_home' %}" class="submenu-link">
```

Главный файл urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('catalog/', include(('catalog.urls', 'catalog'), namespace='catalog')),
    path('user/', include('user.urls')),
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

urls.py приложения:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.catalog_home, name='catalog_home'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.catalog_home, name='catalog_home_by_category'),
    path("filter/", views.FilterCatalogView, name="filter"),
    path("search/", views.Search, name="search"),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug:slug>', views.ShoesDetailView.as_view(), name='shoes-detail')
]
```

Код ошибки:

```
'''


Reverse for 'catalog_home' not found. 'catalog_home' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/
Django Version: 3.2.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'catalog_home' not found. 'catalog_home' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /home/georgy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.10
Python Path:    
['/home/georgy/PycharmProjects/Django_Project/sitepur',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/georgy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 10 Oct 2021 17:16:42 +0000
'''        [![J][1]][1]
```

[image: ошибка]

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос, исправив все ссылки на правильные на странице catalog_home.html:

```
{% url namespace:url_name %}
```